# How can i add a level 2 in my game?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a space invaders-like game. I have finished the first first level which has 4 rows of 10 aliens. I want to add another level where there are 4 rows of 17 aliens to make it difficult and reduce the time limit. I have made a separate module name 'LEVEL2' which is what i have tried to import and run after level one is completed. Can someone please help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance

MAIN GAME(level 1):

```
import pygame, random, sys
from time import sleep
from pygame.locals import *
import subprocess
import LEVEL2

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVYBLUE = (0,0,45)
GREY = (128,128,128)
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 650

pygame.init()
OpenScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])


screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        aliens = pygame.image.load('aliens.png')
        aliens = pygame.transform.scale(aliens, (20,20))
        super(Block, self).__init__()

        self.image = aliens

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
        ship = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
        ship = pygame.transform.scale(ship, (20,30))
        super(Player, self).__init__()

        self.image = ship
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = pos[0]

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        bullets = pygame.image.load('missile.png')
        bullets = pygame.transform.scale(bullets, (15,25))
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.image = bullets
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 1.25

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


for i in range(10):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 200
    block.rect.y = 50
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(10):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 200
    block.rect.y = 75
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(10):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 200
    block.rect.y = 100
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(10):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 200
    block.rect.y = 125
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)




player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
score = 0
time = 3000
player.rect.y = 615
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)



while not done:
    OpenScreen.fill(WHITE)
    fonts = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 55)
    display = fonts.render('PRESS SPACE TO PLAY', True, (BLACK))
    OpenScreen.blit(display, (200 , 200))
    font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 25)
    display1 = font.render("Press Escape to quit", True, (BLACK))
    OpenScreen.blit(display1, (670,600))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            done = True

        elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            while not done:

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

                    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        bullet = Bullet()
                        bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 3.5
                        bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
                        all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                        bullet_list.add(bullet)



                all_sprites_list.update()

                for bullet in bullet_list:
                    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
                    for block in block_hit_list:

                        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                        score += 1
                    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

                screen.fill(NAVYBLUE)
                scoredisplay = font.render("Score {0}".format(score), 1, (WHITE))
                screen.blit(scoredisplay, (5, 10))
                all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
                timedisplay = font.render("Time {0}".format(time), 1, (WHITE))
                screen.blit(timedisplay, (5, 30))
                pygame.display.flip()

                time -= 1
                if time == 0:
                    done = True
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    font= pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 36)
                    display = font.render("YOU RAN OUT OF TIME!! :( Your final score was {}".format(score), 1, (BLACK))
                    screen.blit(display, (100,200))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    pygame.time.wait(1500)

                if len(block_list)  == 0:
                    done == True
                    len(bullet_list) == 0
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    time = 0
                    font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 55)
                    display = font.render('You Won!',True ,(BLACK))
                    display1 = font.render('Press SPACE for Level 2',True ,(BLACK))
                    display2 = font.render('Escape to quit',True ,(BLACK))
                    screen.blit(display,(350,200))
                    screen.blit(display1,(350,400))
                    screen.blit(display2,(500,500))
                    clock.tick(60)
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    pygame.time.wait(1500)
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            done = True
                        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                        if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                            done = True
                        elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                            done = False
                            subprocess.call("LEVEL2.py", shell=True)


pygame.quit()
```

Here is level 2:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from time import sleep
from pygame.locals import *
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVYBLUE = (0,0,45)
GREY = (128,128,128)
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 650

pygame.init()
OpenScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])


screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        aliens = pygame.image.load('aliens.png')
        aliens = pygame.transform.scale(aliens, (20,20))
        super(Block, self).__init__()

        self.image = aliens

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
        ship = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
        ship = pygame.transform.scale(ship, (20,30))
        super(Player, self).__init__()

        self.image = ship
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = pos[0]

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        bullets = pygame.image.load('missile.png')
        bullets = pygame.transform.scale(bullets, (15,25))
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.image = bullets
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 3

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


for i in range(17):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 110
    block.rect.y = 50
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(17):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 110
    block.rect.y = 75
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(17):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 110
    block.rect.y = 100
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(17):
    block = Block(Block)
    block.rect.x = (40 * i) + 110
    block.rect.y = 125
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)




player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
score = 0
time = 2000
player.rect.y = 615
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)



while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            done = True

        elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            while not done:

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

                    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        bullet = Bullet()
                        bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 3.5
                        bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
                        all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                        bullet_list.add(bullet)



                all_sprites_list.update()

                for bullet in bullet_list:
                    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
                    for block in block_hit_list:

                        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                        score += 1
                    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

                screen.fill(NAVYBLUE)
                scoredisplay = font.render("Score {0}".format(score), 1, (WHITE))
                screen.blit(scoredisplay, (5, 10))
                all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
                timedisplay = font.render("Time {0}".format(time), 1, (WHITE))
                screen.blit(timedisplay, (5, 30))
                pygame.display.flip()

                time -= 1
                if time == 0:
                    done = True
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    font= pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 36)
                    display = font.render("YOU RAN OUT OF TIME!! :( Your final score was {}".format(score), 1, (BLACK))
                    screen.blit(display, (100,200))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    pygame.time.wait(1500)

                if len(block_list)  == 0:
                    done == True
                    screen.fill(WHITE)
                    font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 55)
                    display = font.render('You Won!',True ,(BLACK))
                    screen.blit(display,(350,200))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    pygame.time.wait(1500)
                clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Instead of 2 modules of copy and paste code best practice will be to make your game Code conditional on variables passed in, number of ships, lines, speed, level number, and then reuse the same game code with different parameters

Comment: I tried that but wasn't sure exactly how to call different values, for example the for loop which has a range (number of aliens), I don't know how to call it and with a different set of values

Comment: Why not use a variable like level=1, and have an if statement that either runs the level 1 or level 2 depending on that variable?

Answer (score 0):

Take all that stuff in Level 1 *except* the class definitions, and put it into functions with reasonable names like "init" and "playGame."  Let them be members of a class called "Level."

Note what aspects are different in Level 1 and Level 2.  Make these things that are different into parameters into Level's `__init__` member, and use them to initialize some local variable that will be reused by its `playGame` member.

Now makes sure that the playGame and init functions work for both levels.

It just doesn't make sense to rewrite all that code for each level.  This way, you can have as many levels as you want.

Comment: I am a beginner, and am still stuck. Can you please show me how?

Comment: I'd rather see what you wrote, and where you got stuck when you wrote it.  Why don't you give it a try?